# Iphone sdk custom uiview orientation issue

Tags: iphone, uiview, orientation

I am using custom based uiview controller with uitabbar contains uitableview. I am using image for cell background. I want to do orientation from portrait to landscape but the issue is it is not changing on orientation. I just want to know is there are any special thing for custom uiviewcontroller for orientation?

Thanks in advance

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing happens when you rotate the device, you either have the system-wide rotation lock enabled (you checked that, right?), or your view controller isn't returning `YES` to the alternate orientation in its `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, or you're doing something odd with your views that means your view controller isn't getting set as the “frontmost” one and thus isn't getting asked about orientation changes. It'll be easier to narrow that down if you post the code you're using to set up the controller and its view.